# How do I set the availabe of a payment method to false?

Tags: payment-methods

I want to set a payment method by using the payment code to false. This is how I get a list of active paymentcode in checkout:

```
$payments = Mage::getSingleton('payment/config')->getActiveMethods();

        foreach ($payments as $paymentCode=>$paymentModel) {
           if($paymentModel->canUseCheckout() == 1){
                $paymentTitle = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
                $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
                    'label'   => $paymentTitle,
                    'value' => $paymentCode,
                );
           }
        }
```

but i don't know how do i set it to false using the payment code ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to define some configuration in etc.xml of your custom payment method module

```
 <default>
    <payment>
        <custompaymentcode>
            <active>0</active>
            <model>modulealias/paymentmodel</model>
            <order_status>pending_payment</order_status>
            <title>Custom Payment Method 1</title>
        </custompaymentcode>
    </payment>
</default>
```

In your Payment Model which normally extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract` if you are not using CC methods

add below function

```
public function isAvailable($quote = null)
{ return false; }
```